# Can you make complete apps using Flutter & Dart or just the UI part of an app?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, cross-platform, mobile-application

I'm confused about what Flutter framework actually does, I know that it uses Dart and have heard that both of them can be used to create cross-platform apps.

But Wikipedia defines Flutter as a "UI Framework", so my question is, **can you make a complete app (for mobile) which also has backend part (communicates with a database) built entirely using Flutter & Dart and not only the UI part?**

Comment: You can create complete apps using Flutter.

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/ for more info

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can obviously build complete apps using Flutter, from UI part to backend as well. Using Firebase as a backend service, we can use it for authentication, database, hosting and all.